# MySQL JOIN with two tables and using IFNULL. Results vary between MySQL versions

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, mysql-5.6

I have 3 tables:

- **color**: fixed list of original color names and their HEX.
- **store_color**: custom color names (optional). For example if you want the color red to be call "deadpool red"
- **store_product_color**: colors associated to a specific product ID.

This is the query causing the issue:

```
SELECT
store_product_color.id AS id,
store_product_color.id_color AS id_color,
color.hex AS hex,
IFNULL(store_color.name, color.name) AS name
FROM store_product_color
JOIN color ON color.id_color = store_product_color.id_color
LEFT JOIN store_color ON store_color.id_color = store_product_color.id_color
WHERE store_product_color.id_product = 176
ORDER BY store_product_color.id_color
```

It returns the id of the product association (primary), the id of the color, the color hex, and if a custom name exists, it should be used, else, use the original color name.

The query works perfect in my dev environment:

**MySQL 5.6.25**

[image: 2 results in MySQL 5.6.25]

Here comes the tricky part. The production environment uses another version of MySQL and the results vary from the dev environment. Instead of choosing between the custom and original color name, it creates 2 different rows, one for each name.

**MySQL 5.6.30**

[image: 3 results in MySQL 5.6.30]

I also tried removing `IFNULL(store_color.name, color.name) AS name` and adding `store_color.name AS name2, color.name AS name1` but the issue remains.

I was unable to replicate this issue in sqlfiddle or db-fiddle. I added a live example, but it works fine just like it does on my dev environment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/25J8Kh8m8GSoHzw9MUJ67M/2

What can be causing this issue and how do I solve it? **Thanks**!

Comment: Your query is fine.  The data is different.

Comment: That's just an example, the data presents itself in a different way in both servers.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i updated the db-fiddle example with the same data as the screenshots. It does work in the db-fiddle, but it displays the wrong results in the environment server with MySQL 5.6.30

Comment: So versions have bugs, is always recomemned to update to the last version 5.6.47 is the last. or switch entirely to something more recent. you can check the changeliog between the two version you have to see what the developer has fixed.